# Unity 5.5 - Modify image of a button from an array of images via script - Logic Help

Tags: unity, logic, ui-design

Right now i have this:

[image]

Is a placeholder for what i want to do. This blue circles are images in different buttons, i have a blue image circle for every letter. I have to display the correct letter image to create a word. For example: word: "DOG" and the word is created by the "D" "O" "G" images.

That is the logic i cannot get my head around.

**How can I, via script, select which image to show depending on the word given?**

**IDEAS:**

- I have an array of (INDEX, "letter") in my GameController.CS. Maybe i can add a number to the different images name. Separeate the word in characters. Look the position of this character in the Letters[] and that number turn it into a string and find the image with that number in the name.

I really need help to figure this out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If all the images are characters why not just make each name of the image the letter alone (D.png/O.jpg or whatever), and search the array for that letter, and set it based on that. (WhateverYouAreSetting = Letters[ChosenLetter] + ".png"). Don't do excess coverting with numbers, strings and chars.

Comment: @n_palum i already managed to accomplish this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've created a simple solution to get you started.

Assuming you have 26 images of the letters (or a multi-image sprite which is what I used) do the following:

1. Create a project, include the images in the project as assets.
2. Create two empty objects, we'll call them `Letter` and `LetterMgr`
3. Add a sprite renderer to `Letter`. This will be our template object.
4. Add a script file called `LetterMgr.cs` and add it to the `LetterMgr` object.
5. Add the following code to the script:

   ```
   public GameObject LetterTemplate;

   public Sprite[] TheLetters;

   void Start () {
       var theWord = "Lilo";
       var letters = theWord.ToUpper().ToCharArray();
       var position = Vector3.zero;
       var spacing = Vector3.right * 2;
       foreach (var letter in letters) {
           var letterIndex = letter - 65; // uppercase A is 65
           var letterObj = Instantiate(LetterTemplate, position, Quaternion.identity);
           letterObj.name = letter.ToString();
           letterObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = TheLetters[letterIndex];
           position += spacing;
       }

   }
   ```
6. In the Scene editor, click the `LetterMgr` to show its properties.
7. Click the little lock icon at the top right of the inspector (this is **important** for the next steps).
8. select all the letter images (**order is important**, click the first one and then shift-click the last) and drag them to the "The Letters" property in the inspector.
   [image: Dragging the letter sprites]
9. Select the `Letter` object and drag it to the "Letter Template" property.
10. Run the project. You should get a result similar to this:
    [image: Result of running the script]